# How to Programmatically get a handle on a JSF View/Page that is not the Current ViewId

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I would like to programmatically get a handle on a JSF .xhtml view/page other than the current one and be able to arbitrarily insert or plug it into the current view if possible. I want to use this together with ajax to update the current view depending on user input. I do not want to go the `<ui:include src="#{bean.property}">` route and also do not want to build the page programmatically in a bean. Please help, been stuck on this for a good week now.

Thank you,

Comment: Dynamic include would be the answer to that. If you don't want that, then well, I think it stops here. Maybe you should take a step back and ask about the problems you faced while using dynamic include.

Comment: thanks for that quick response BalusC. Actually your are right. I was failing to see how I could use the `<ui:include>` as part of an ajax setup. Now I am just realising that that I can. Thanks once again. But then again BalusC, why is it one cant get a handle to a jsf file and access programmatically the jsf components in there?

Comment: It's possible, but it's fishy to manipulate the view in the model while it should be the other way round.